# How to add shapes/decoration correctly to the page layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I know it might be a duplicated question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else in the internet.

**Question is very simple:** I want to know how should/could I add shapes/decoration to the page layout correctly so it will not look broken inside a responsive container.

[Click here to see the picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uy41.png)
Actually I don't know the way to add that much shapes without making some mess in the code or completely braking the responsiveness of the container itself. If anybody already have done this, please describe your solution/method of doing this correctly. Thank you in advance and hope this will be useful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set a `position : relative` in the parent element and then use `position: absolut;` with relative unites.

Also take care to have a lower `z-index` for the decorations:

```css
section {
    background-color: rgb(69, 83, 95);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vh;
}

.content {
    z-index: 2;
}

.element {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
}

.element1 {
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}

.element2 {
    top: 80%;
    left: 30%;
}

.element3 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 70%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <span class="element element1">+</span>
    <span class="element element2">*</span>
    <span class="element element3">*</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I just wanted to understand correctly, you are using % to make them responsive in the end? And how should I better create these figures: with css or attach each one as an icon ?

Comment: yes,% is useful to always have the same space in proportion. I think use SVG is the easiest solution

Comment: One last question, if I will make it with svg for example, will it be a correct way to do this, wont it affect the page loading time ?

Answer (score 0):

As the decorations are just that, with no particular meaning that for example would be read out by a screen reader, I would put them in as background images - either as SVGs or gradients (if suitable) and position and size each one in terms of %s relative to the dimensions of the main element.

That way you have a responsive page and you haven't cluttered up the HTML with elements.

Each of the decorations seems separate, but if they overlap then remember the one that comes first in the background-image list will be shown on top of one coming afterwards.

So you are going to end up with CSS looking something like this:

```
background-image: url(svg1), url(svg2), url(svg3)...;
background-position: x1% y1%, x2% y2%, x3% y3%,...;
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
background-size: w1% h1%, w2% h2%, w3% h3%,...;
```

It's easy to work out the percentages, just use a ruler on the image - any units will do, and divide by the width or height of the main element as appropriate * 100.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, this was very useful and a really easy way to do, I appreciate this a lot !